# How to toggle scientific notation in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, scientific-notation

I am trying to solving pythonchallenge problem using Clojure:

```
(java.lang.Math/pow 2 38)
```

I got

```
2.74877906944E11
```

However, I need to turn off this scientific notation. I searched clojure docs, still don't know what to do. Is there a general way to toggle on/off scientific notation in Clojure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [format](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/format) to control how results are printed.

```
user> (format "%.0f" (Math/pow 2 38))
"274877906944"
```

Also, if there is no danger of losing wanted data, you can cast to an exact type:

```
user> 274877906944.0
2.74877906944E11
user> (long 274877906944.0)
274877906944
```

There are BigInts for larger inputs

```
user> (bigint 27487790694400000000.0)
27487790694400000000N
```

Comment: It works, thank you! And what if I want to convert a big number to its scientific notation?

Comment: It uses the formats of the java Formatter http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html - so %E (with optional prefix for precision control).

Comment: Thanks very much! "%e" does work. If the number is not of **float type**, I have to `(float the-number)` first. That's also logical.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**

You can often lose precision by using `java.lang.Math/pow` to compute an integer power of an integer.

For example

```
(bigint (java.lang.Math/pow 3 38))
; 1350851717672992000N
```

whereas

```
(int-pow 3 38)
; 1350851717672992089
```

It works with powers of `2` because - if you look at them in binary - there is a single `1` bit with all the rest `0`s. So the hex exponent just keeps going up while the solitary `1` bit floats around in the [significand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand). No precision is lost.

By the way, `int-pow` above is just repeated multiplication:

```
(defn int-pow [b ^long ex]
  (loop [acc 1, ex ex]
    (case ex
      0 acc
      (recur (* acc b) (dec ex)))))
```

---

This is more a comment than a solution, but doesn't fit as such.

Comment: Thank you. I shall come back here for reference when I come across large number computation.

Comment: @Nick You can find a gentle introduction [here](http://aphyr.com/posts/302-clojure-from-the-ground-up-basic-types). The standard books, *Programming Clojure* and *Clojure Programming*, cover the topic well - worth getting both, IMO. Don't use old editions, though: some of the details changed a couple of years ago (with Clojure version 1.3, I think). All the best and enjoy it!

Comment: Thanks Thumbnail. I am reading Clojure programming (OReilly), it's a great book. I am new to the programming world without computer science background, so it's a little hard for me. Fortunately, people from Clojure community are very helpful and very nice --- which also encourages me a lot.

Comment: A long time past, I find this post again. I think this `int-pow` might be easier to read: `(defn int-pow [base exp]
  (if (zero? exp)
    1N
    (* base (int-pow base (dec exp)))))`

Comment: @Nick Yes. It is easier to read. But it is properly recursive, so slower and limited to `exp` less than 10K or so, with normal JVM parameters.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just read this fast exponentiation algorithm from SICP: `(defn fast-expt [b n]
  (cond (zero? n) 1N
        (even? n) (square (fast-expt b (/ n 2)))
        :else (* b (fast-expt b (dec n)))))

(defn- square [n]
  (* n n))` This can compute `3^20K` in about 22 mses.

Comment: @Nick Yes - logarithmic in `n`. But prefer `quot` to `/`.